# What is this IC marked A6505 01230?

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, identification, protection, tvs

Can you help me find this IC marked A6505 01230?

[image]

Comment: Please provide further context - such as the purpose of the board the IC is on, the IC's pinout, dimensions & periphery, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [Bourns TBU-CA065-050-WH](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/54/TBU-CA-778169.pdf) Surge Suppressor.

[image]